# pandas MultiIndex: insert a row at top and keep first level of index hidden

Tags: python, pandas

In MultiIndex dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [['a', 'b', 2, 3], ['c', 'b', 5, 6], ['a','c', 8, 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['I1', 'I2', 'v1', 'v2'])
df = df.groupby(['I1', 'I2']).first()
```

I want to insert a row `ex` at top and keep the first level of MultiIndex hidden. The expected result is

[image]

I tried `concat`:

```
data_ex = {'v1':[99], 'v2': [98]}
df_ex = pd.DataFrame(data_ex, index = [('ex','ex')])
pd.concat([df_ex, df])
```

However it become

[image]

I also tried first concat without index, then groupby multiply index. But pandas will automatically sort by MultiIndex. As a result, ex row cannot be set at top.

Comment: What do you want the results to be? Can you please provide coded examples?

Comment: @ArchAngelPwn `insert a row at top and keep the first level of multiple index hidden`. the form of screen shot of excel is just the expected output. I cannot generate such result by code

Comment: I see let me look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need pass the correct index format

```
df_ex = pd.DataFrame(data_ex, index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('ex','ex')],names=["I1", "I2"]))

pd.concat([df_ex, df])
Out[783]: 
       v1  v2
I1 I2        
ex ex  99  98
a  b    2   3
   c    8   9
c  b    5   6
```

Comment: so, the MultiIndex is not simply a tuple?

Comment: @user6703592 Nope, but tuples are a way to access elements in MultiIndex.

Comment: and how to keep the index name I1 I2？

Comment: @user6703592 check the updated ~

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `pd.MultiIndex` first.

```
import pandas as pd
a = [['a', 'b', 2, 3], ['c', 'b', 5, 6], ['a','c', 8, 9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['I1', 'I2', 'v1', 'v2'])
df = df.groupby(['I1', 'I2']).first()

data_ex = {'v1':[99], 'v2': [98]}
df_ex = pd.DataFrame(data_ex, index = [('ex','ex')])
# create multi-index from the index of tuples
df_ex.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df_ex.index)
# name the columns of the multi-index
df_ex.index.names = ["I1", "I2"]

pd.concat([df_ex, df], axis=0)
```